# Hold a type in a Golang struct field

Tags: reflection, struct, go

I'm looking for a way to hold a type (maybe reflection.Type?) as a field in a custom struct. The reasoning behind this is that I'm decoding JSON arrays into structs from which I later build SQL queries, but ints, floats and timestamps are identical in the JSON array, though they are different when querying a database. This means I need to convert each value to its correct type before querying.

I think the answer lies somewhere in the reflect package, but I haven't worked out exactly how to utilize it.

What I'm hoping for is something like this:

```
type Column struct {
    name string
    dataType type
}
someColumn := Column {name: "somecol", dataType: int}
convertedVal := SomeConversionFunc("5", someColumn.dataType)
```

Alternatively, this sort of thing could work as well:

```
type Column struct {
    name string
    dataType func()
}
someColumn := Column {name: "somecol", dataType: ConvertToInt}
convertedVal := someColumn.dataType("5")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: seems you need a ORM package.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the solution. Everything is decoded as a string, which means I need to convert these strings to their corresponding columns' data types before passing them to the query builder (I'm using squirrel to create Cassandra queries - CQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted to use the solution offered by @evanmcdonnal but I could not find a generic way of converting `float64` (which is the type `json.Unmarshal` gives to any number it unmarshals from the json array) to any data type found in the DB (`timestamp` proved to be a bit tricky, because `reflect.Value` does not export a conversion method to `time.Time`, which is the equivalent of Cassandra's `timestamp`).

What did work was using a `typeConversion` field instead of a `dataType` field, that is, holding a function that converts to the distined column's type from the type `json.Unmarshal` sets the variable's type to.

My struct, therefore, looks like this:

```
type Column struct {
    name string
    typeConversion func(reflect.Value) reflect.Value
}
```

Some typeConversion functions I already have look like this:

```
func floatToTime(varFloat reflect.Value) reflect.Value {
    timestamp := time.Unix(int64(varFloat.Float()), 0)
    return reflect.ValueOf(timestamp)
}

func floatToInt(varFloat reflect.Value) reflect.Value {
    return reflect.ValueOf(int(varFloat.Float()))
}
```

This actually happens to be a very good solution, because it is extremely generic: the struct defines the way any conversion function should be built, which means I can wrap any form of conversion to fit this API, and because the return value is always `reflect.Value`, I can access the underlying value with the correct type by calling `Interface()`, like so:

```
// value is the data unmarshaled by json
// I convert it to reflect.Value, then convert it again using my custom typeConversion
// Then  I use Interface() to get the final value in the final (and column-appropriate) type
column.typeConversion(reflect.ValueOf(value)).Interface()
```

Comment: This put me on the right track. I have a struct member of type reflect.Type, and assign it the value reflect.TypeOf(variable).

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track I suppose. In your `Column` struct you're looking for `reflect.Type`. Which you'll get with `import "reflect"`.

If your column struct contains the type name and value (as a raw string) you should be able to write method that switches on type and produces a value of the correct type for each case. Brief reference for switches here; https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#switch

```
type Column struct {
    Name string
    DataType reflect.Type
    TypedValue interface{}
    StringValue string
}
```

Because you said "but ints, floats and timestamps are identical in the JSON array" I'm assuming all the values in your json are technically strings (meaning they're all quoted). You may not need all those fields but the idea is to have the type information coupled with the properties name and the original value. If you use the field of type `interface{}` you can assign anything to it so you could hold the original json data (name and value) as well as the type information and the value in a sensible Go type in an instance of this struct pretty easily.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow. Should the `dataType` field be a string or a `reflect.Type`? If it is a `reflect.Type`, then how do I enter an int type, for example? If it is a string, is there a function which converts using strings to represent the desired type?

Comment: @SivanBH `dataType` should be a `reflect.Type`. For any instance `i` (of any type) you can get it's type with `reflect.TypeOf`. I'll edit with a sample of a model that I think would be more reasonable. I'm going to have all the fields exported, you can change that to suite your needs.

Comment: This is as far as I've gotten as well, but it doesn't seem to work. If, for example, `DataType` should be int, I use `reflect.Int`, but that's not actually a `reflect.Type`, but a `reflect.Kind`. And either way, the conversion method provided by reflect only works as a method implemented by `reflect.Value`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The [StructTag](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) should help:

```
type Table struct {
    age int `sql:"type:int;`
    price float `sql:"type:float;`
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution I haven't come across. It does not suit my needs though, because I am using maps to represent column-to-value's requested by the user.